# Magento 2 installation step "Solving 403 Forbidden errors for Apache 2.4"

Tags: magento2, error, installation, apache2, http-status-403

In [this guideline from Magento2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#403-apache) there are talking about how to solve the 403 forbidden errors for Apache 2.4, and they are saying that I have to put this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride <value from Apache site>
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in "your Apache configuration or your virtual host configuration".
Now my questions:

> **1. where is that Apache configuration file? and/or where is my virtual host configuration file?
>
>    2. in the above tag, what is the value of "`<value from Apache site>`"? where can I find it?**

*Please note that my Magento2 directory is **"/var/www/Magento2"***

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This varies from system to system. Ask your hoster or add information about your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have permissions correct, before you set `Require all granted`.

ususally `AllowOverride <value from Apache site>` = `AllowOverride All`

to find your config:

```
httpd -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG
```

or like this

```
httpd -S
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: when I'm running any of the commands you have posted, I am getting:
 "No command 'httpd' found, did you mean" then it list another three commands..... just to make it clear, I am asking about where to place that <Directory /var/www/> tag ... do those commands return the path of that file?

Comment: find your apache binary and use these commands then

Comment: YMMV of course but for Apache 2.4, look here: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. For Apache 2.2, look here: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: Thanks Steve... but where exactly in that file I should put that tag? at the end? or it does not matter!.... please execuse me but I'm so shallow in this :(

Comment: Add it to the appropriate <Directory> directive, such as the one you show in your original comment.